# How can I render data, which I receive from two different inputs, in the UI that I am rendering, using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-props, array.prototype.map

I am creating a Todo List using React and Firebase. At the moment, I am able to add a todo, and have it render in the UI, which is a list that I import and map through. The problem, is that when I try and add an additional input, I am not able to render the second input, and only the first input gets rendered. Taking this into consideration I decided to console.log the two inputs, and I saw that the data was available in the console. I then previously created a question on Stackoverflow, thinking that my problem was the props I was expecting in the child component. But now, I think my issue lies with how my data is being passed down, to be mapped and then rendered. For example, my todo is being passed as an argument, but I also need my title to be passed as an argument when I map through my list elemnt. So my question is more about how can I get both pieces of data to render in my UI.

This is the parent component. AddLink.js.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classes from "./addlink.module.css";
    
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import initFirebase from "../../config";
import "firebase/firestore";

import Todo from "../Todo/Todo";

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

initFirebase();
const db = firebase.firestore();

function AddLink(props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inputLinks, setInputLinks] = useState("");
  const [inputHeaders, setInputHeaders] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("links")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setTodos(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            todo: doc.data().todo,
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("links").add({
      id: uuidv4(),
      todo: inputLinks,
      title: inputHeaders,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    console.log(inputLinks);
    console.log(inputHeaders);
    setInputLinks("");
    setInputHeaders("");
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.addlink}>
      <form>
        <div className={classes.adminlink}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputLinks}
            onChange={(event) => setInputLinks(event.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputHeaders}
            onChange={(event) => setInputHeaders(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className={classes.adminbutton}
            type="submit"
            onClick={addTodo}
          >
            Add new link
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {todos.map((todo, title) => (
        <Todo id={todo.id} todo={todo} title={todo.title} key={todo.id} />
      ))}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddLink;
```

And the child component Todo.js.

```
import React from "react";
import { AiOutlinePicture } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiOutlineStar } from "react-icons/ai";
import { GoGraph } from "react-icons/go";
import DeleteForeverIcon from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever";

import classes from "./todo.module.css";

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import initFirebase from "../../config";
import "firebase/firestore";

initFirebase();
const db = firebase.firestore();

function Todo(props) {
  const deleteHandler = (event) => {
    db.collection("links").doc(props.todo.id).delete();
  };

  return (
    <li className={classes.adminsection}>
      <div className={classes.linkCards}>
        <h3>{props.todo.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.todo.todo}</p>
        <div>
          <AiOutlinePicture />
          <AiOutlineStar />
          <GoGraph />
          <DeleteForeverIcon onClick={deleteHandler} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code looks familiar. Are you just trying to pass `todo.title` to render in the `Todo` component? It seems it should be available either on the `todo` prop as `props.todo.title`, or it looks like you also directly pass a `title` prop, so `props.title` should also work. Can you log out your `todos` state to share with us it's shape from when you unpack it from firebase with `doc.data().todo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i saw that code also once before. You are adding the data in a wrong way and also reading it from the map the wrong way. Here is an example how it should work:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import classes from "./addlink.module.css";

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import initFirebase from "../../config";
import "firebase/firestore";

import Todo from "../Todo/Todo";

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

initFirebase();
const db = firebase.firestore();

function AddLink(props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inputLinks, setInputLinks] = useState("");
  const [inputHeaders, setInputHeaders] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("links")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setTodos(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            todo: doc.data(),
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    db.collection("links").add({
      id: uuidv4(),
      todo: inputLinks,
      title: inputHeaders,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    console.log(inputLinks);
    console.log(inputHeaders);
    setInputLinks("");
    setInputHeaders("");
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.addlink}>
      <form>
        <div className={classes.adminlink}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputLinks}
            onChange={(event) => setInputLinks(event.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputHeaders}
            onChange={(event) => setInputHeaders(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className={classes.adminbutton}
            type="submit"
            onClick={addTodo}
          >
            Add new link
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {todos.map((i) => (
        <Todo id={i.id} todo={i.todo} title={i.todo.title} key={i.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddLink;
```

The mistakes:

- here the `todo` is taking just part of the data:

```
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            todo: doc.data().todo,
          }))
```

- here you need to consider that you saved a single object and you need to read it as one

```js
{todos.map((todo, title) => (
        <Todo id={todo.id} todo={todo} title={todo.title} key={todo.id} />
      ))}
```

Comment: It looks like the earlier change from my previous post and the change where I map through, fixed the problem. Thank you for all your help. The only issue is my delete functionality has also been affected, as I am deleting based on id `db.collection("links").doc(props.todo.id).delete();`. Do you know of any good resources that I could use to help me understand this better?

Comment: You can delete it like this: `db.collection("links").doc(props.id).delete();` The basic thing you missed here is that map is always giving you the "thing" you map trough and the index on witch it is as first and second parameter. You pushed in your array you map trough a object and as that you need to be aware that in your `map` the first parameter is an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map